# How to set the IGNORE flag in mysqlsh importTable util?

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile, mysql-8.0

The following triggers a `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement in `mysql8`:

```
util.importTable("sample.csv", {schema: "myschema", table: "mytable", dialect: "csv-unix", fieldsTerminatedBy: ";", showProgress: true})
```

Question: how can I add the `IGNORE INTO` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`util.importTable` is using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and ignores duplicate-keys by default[1]. If you want replace duplicate-keys set `replaceDuplicates` option to `true`.

[1] [MySQL Reference Manual for LOAD DATA Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

> **Duplicate-Key Handling**
>
> (…) With LOCAL, the default behavior is the same as if IGNORE is specified; this is because the server has no way to stop transmission of the file in the middle of the operation.